# Ubuntu 11.04 screen freezes after login

Tags: display, wireless-networking, freeze, ethernet, ubuntu-11.04

After using *airmon-ng* and disabling eth0 and wlan0, and restarting my computer in dual boot mode under Ubuntu 11.04 my computer froze right after logging into Ubuntu. I tried re-enabling eth0 and wlan0, but i'm not sure if it was done properly.

When I plug an Ethernet cable into my computer it starts up with no problems, no freezing, no nothing. However, when I unplug the cable the computer freezes shortly after. I figure that this issue may revolve around a wireless related process? If this isn't solved could I reinstall Ubuntu 11.04 in dual boot without having to worry about the 20GB of partitioned space that I allocated it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

> http://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/index.php/2011/04/30/turning-wireless-on-causes-laptop-to-freeze-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-my-work-around/